# Distorted mesh / texture

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: distorted material]
[image: edit_mode]
[image: object_mode]
[image: reference photo]
I have the chrome material assigned to the correct faces, but when I render the image they show up longer than the faces they are on. It looks like the edges are aligned to the chrome areas in the reference image, in edit mode, but not in object mode. I have tried applying scale, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: in your Subdivision Surface modifier, is there a difference between the Viewport and Render subdivision values?

Comment: No. They are both set to 1.